# how to change backgound of button in swift?

Tags: swift

I have initialized a UIbutton(frame:) but i can't change the background color of the button

```
   var index:Int = 0;
        let heightView = view.frame.height
        for item in arr {
            
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: index, y: 0, width: item.count * 11, height: Int(heightView)))
            index = index + item.count * 11
            button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
            button.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

            view.addSubview(button)
            print(button.frame)
        }
```

Comment: width: item.count * 11, Here item is an array?

Comment: Here, I don't know how wide the button has to be to fit the title, Do you have a better way?

Comment: Ok, I have better way but your code should show error. Is it showing error now?

Comment: mine doesn't currently have errors

Comment: You are using title as **item** and also you are using **item.count**. It is ambiguous. Here item is not an array. So it should not have .count property.

Comment: @Imran0001 I suppose Item is a string here and thus has a count property for the number of characters. This width calculation would only work for monospaced fonts and even then it's not a clean solution.

Comment: To answer you question, your line: `backgroundColor = .red` is correct. The problem might actually comes from the dimension of your button. What does `print(button.frame)` returns? To check that the dimension are ok, you could use the xCode "Debug View Hierarchy" feature and see what your button looks like.